# R function for generalized distances between rankings

Tags: r, distance, rank

I'm trying to calculate the distances between ranked lists of a specific form. For example,

1. 0.30  itemA1  |  0.40  itemB1
2. 0.25  itemA2  |  0.30  itemB2
3. 0.20  itemA3  |  0.20  itemB3

where 1,2,3 are the positions of the elements in the two lists that are separated by the |, the decimal values are the weights of the elements in each list, and the items A1,2,3,B1,2,3 are values of the same class, with some distance among one another.

Given these requirements, I'm interested in putting together an R function for Kumar et al. (2010)'s generalized distance between rankings--an extension of Kendall's tau and Spearman's footrule: eqns 11 and 12 in

http://theory.stanford.edu/~sergei/papers/www10-metrics.pdf

which incorporate the weights of the elements being swapped, as well as their positions in the list. I've looked at different R packages (TopKLists, RankAggreg, Kendall), but none I have come across implement the Kumar et al. distance.

Has anyone encountered an R function for this distance? I emailed the author, and he suggested some partially complete python code on a git repo as a starting point:

https://gist.github.com/pilipolio/7655572

However, I am not familiar with python, and the code appears (to me) to be either incomplete (not including eqns 11 and 12), or nonfunctional.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If I understand the paper correctly it describes a weighted version of Spearman's footrule distance.  There is an R package (not by Kumar or citing his work) that implements such a distance measure: http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/pmr/html/wdbm.html . It's possible that these are independent inventions of equivalent measures.